# OrientDb check if edge exists in one direction

Tags: orientdb

I am using orientdb and i am expanding all those vertices which are following me. Now i am also following some of the vertices so I want to check if i am following a particular vertex or not.

The query i am using:

```
SELECT @rid, name FROM (SELECT expand(in('Follow')) FROM users WHERE @rid = #123:8 LIMIT 20)
```

And i have tried to do

```
SELECT @rid as userRid, name, if(SELECT FROM follow where out = #123:8 And in = userRid, 1, 0) as followed FROM (SELECT expand(in('follow')) FROM users WHERE @rid = #123:8 LIMIT 20)
```

Any idea how to achieve the expected results?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using orientdb 2.2.0

Comment: I am from MySQL background and the query inside 'if' in mysql works but its not working in orientdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select from <your rid> where out('Follow').@rid contains <person rid>
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: It works. But how to use it as a sub query? Like i want to use it with

SELECT rid as userRid, name, if(select from <your rid> where out('Follow').rid contains <person rid>, 1, 0) as followed FROM (SELECT expand(in('follow')) FROM users WHERE @rid = #123:8 LIMIT 20)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with the answer of Michela Bonizzi, I manage to solve it like this

```
SELECT @rid, name, if(eval("in('Follow') contains #123:8"), 1, 0) as followed FROM (SELECT expand(in('Follow')) FROM users WHERE @rid = #123:8 LIMIT 20)
```

Now this one will going to tell me if i follow my followers too. So the answer of Michela is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let (Source)-->(Target)

It is possible to verify if an edge exists in both directions

```
SELECT IN('EDGE_CLASS').sourceProperty FROM (SELECT FROM Target WHERE targetProperty = 'value')

SELECT OUT('EDGE_CLASS').targetProperty FROM (SELECT FROM Source WHERE sourceProperty = 'value')
```

Alternatively, you can use an alias and EXPAND function to get the property of interest.

```
SELECT EXPAND(IN('EDGE_CLASS').sourceProperty) AS sourceProperty FROM (SELECT FROM Target WHERE targetProperty = 'value')
```